# Unable to install bower install any package permission denied unlink issue

Tags: php, laravel, bower

After installing bower through npm install -g bower
and updating it . This is what i got. when trying to install jquery or any packages. I am on a macos.

```
Stack trace:
Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/ericheng/.cache/bower/registry/registry.bower.io/lookup/jquery_d223e'

Console trace:
Error
    at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:88:37)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:113:30)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at Logger.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:49:24
    at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:864:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:890:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1142:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:808:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
System info:
Bower version: 1.8.4
Node version: 11.9.0
OS: Darwin 18.0.0 x64
```

Answer (score -1):

In the end i just ran it like this 
sudo bower install --allow-root
just not sure how to not do this without sudo. something to do with i dont have proper permissions on some files